# FullCalendar implementation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am implementing FullCalendar in a RoR project and I got this error when I try to update a row :

> `PATCH http://127.0.0.1:3000/events 404 (Not Found)`

Here is the Ajax call to update a row when I click on an event :

```
$.ajax({
                        type: 'PATCH', // Use PATCH or PUT depending on your Rails routes
                        url: '/events/' + eventId, // Adjust the URL to your Rails route

                        data: {
                            event: {
                                title: 'updatedTitle',
                                start_date: 'updatedStartDate',
                                end_date: 'updatedEndDate',
                                description: 'updatedDescription'
                            }
                        },
                        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response.status === 'success') {
                                // Update the event data in FullCalendar
                                arg.event.setProp('title', updatedTitle);
                                arg.event.setStart(updatedStartDate);
                                arg.event.setEnd(updatedEndDate);
                                arg.event.setExtendedProp('description', updatedDescription);

                                // Close the modal
                                $('#eventModal').modal('hide');

                                // Display a success message (you can use Swal or other methods)
                                Swal.fire({
                                    text: 'Event updated successfully',
                                    icon: 'success',
                                    buttonsStyling: false,
                                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok, got it!',
                                    customClass: {
                                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                // Handle the case where the update failed
                                Swal.fire({
                                    text: 'Event update failed: ' + response.message,
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    buttonsStyling: false,
                                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok, got it!',
                                    customClass: {
                                        confirmButton: 'btn btn-primary',
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log('AJAX request to Rails failed.');
                            console.log(error)
                        },
                    });
```

I console.logged my eventId and it's correctyl implemented (its value is 76). I don't understand why the url used by the Ajax call is url: '/events/'

Here is my routes.rb file :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :telephones


  get 'home/index'
  resources :tickets
  resources :imprimantes
  resources :voitures
  resources :telephones
  resources :events

  resources :events do
    collection do
    post 'import_ics'
    get 'export_ics'
  end
end

  # Define a route for updating events using PATCH
  patch '/events/:id', to: 'events#update', as: 'update_event'

  resources :google_calendar, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]


  root 'home#index'

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "posts#index"
end
```

And the update function :

```
def update
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      if @event.update(event_params)
        redirect_to events_path
      else
        render 'edit'
      end


 def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start_date, :end_date, :description)
end
    end
```

What did I miss ?

Edit : Rails console logs

```
    Started PATCH "/events/68" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-11-14 23:55:04 +0100
Processing by EventsController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"event"=>{"title"=>"updatedTitle", "start_date"=>"updatedStartDate", "end_date"=>"updatedEndDate", "description"=>"updatedDescription"}, "id"=>"68"}
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`id` = 68 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:42:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (15.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `update'
  Event Update (11.3ms)  UPDATE `events` SET `events`.`title` = 'updatedTitle', `events`.`start_date` = NULL, `events`.`end_date` = NULL, `events`.`description` = 'updatedDescription', `events`.`updated_at` = '2023-11-14 22:55:04.903524' WHERE `events`.`id` = 68
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (8.0ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `update'
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/events
Completed 302 Found in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 35.5ms | Allocations: 4141)


Started PATCH "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-11-14 23:55:04 +0100
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/events"):
```

Comment: Can you please add Rails log for this request?

Comment: Run ``bin/rails routes | grep events`` to see if you have the correct routes and post the output.

Comment: Did you restart the server after updating `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Rails logs, it looks like your JS fires a valid request and it updates a record. The thing is that in the controller on successfull update you redirect to the events_path

```rb
if @event.update(event_params)
  redirect_to events_path
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

Could you try adding a piece of logic which differentiate between mime types of requests?

something like:

```rb
def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.update(event_params)
      format.html { redirect_to events_path }
      format.json { render json: { status: :success } }
    else
      format.html { render 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: { status: :unprocessable_entity } }
    end
  end
end
```

link to source [Mime responds](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)

Also you should add an Accept header in the ajax call. Your ajax call should look like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'PATCH',
  url: '/events/1',
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
  data: {
    event: {
      title: 'new_title'
    }
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    // Handle your response
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.error(response)
    // Handle your error
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried this code, and got the same error

Comment: I see, try adding a header 'Accept: "application/json"' in the ajax call. You should also change the format in the controller from js to json.

Comment: Perfect it works ! Thank you very much